# Missing NULL when Create CMS code sigining with openssl

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509certificate, codesign, code-signing-certificate

when I try to code signing a file with openssl cms, I expected to get following resualt:

```
 2 30   13:   SEQUENCE {
 4 06    9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER '2 16 840 1 101 3 4 2 1'
 15 05    0:     NULL
 :     }
```

but eventualy will finished with missing NULLs!

```
 2 30   11:   SEQUENCE {
 4 06    9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER '2 16 840 1 101 3 4 2 1'
 :     }
```

to create cms, I use a self-signed certificate. with following steps:
1st: create a self signed Root certificate as follow:

`openssl req -new -nodes -utf8 -sha256 -days 3650 -batch -x509 -config cnf.cnf -outform PEM -out rootca.pem -keyout rootca_pri.pem`

cnf file as follow:

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no
string_mask = utf8only
x509_extensions = extensions

[ req_distinguished_name ]
C = xx
O = xxxxxx
CN = xxxxxx

[ extensions ]
subjectKeyIdentifier = keyid
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always, issuer
basicConstraints = CA:TRUE
keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign
```

2nd: Create Code CA:

```
openssl genrsa -out codeca_pri.pem 2048
openssl req -new -config codeca.cnf -out codeca.csr -key codeca_pri.pem
openssl x509 -req -in codeca.csr -CA rootca.pem -CAkey rootca_pri.pem -CAcreateserial -out codeca.pem -days 365 -extensions extensions -extfile cnf.cnf
```

with following cnf:

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no
string_mask = utf8only
x509_extensions = extensions

[ req_distinguished_name ]
C = xxx
O = xxxxxxxxx
CN = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[ extensions ]
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid, issuer
subjectKeyIdentifier = keyid
extendedKeyUsage =critical, codeSigning
basicConstraints =critical, CA:TRU
EkeyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign
```

3rd: Create a cert signing:

```
openssl genrsa -out signcert_pri.pem 2048
openssl req -new -config cercnf.cnf -out signcert.csr -key signcert_pri.pem
openssl x509 -req -in ./cert/signcert.csr -CA codeca.pem -CAkey codeca_pri.pem -CAcreateserial -out signcert.pem -days 365 -extensions extensions -extfile cnf.cnf
```

cnf file:

```
[ req ]
default_bits = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no
string_mask = utf8only
x509_extensions = extensions

[ req_distinguished_name ]
C = xxx
ST=xxxxx
L=xxxxxxxxxx
O = xxxxxxxxxxxx
CN = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

[ extensions ]
subjectKeyIdentifier = keyid
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid, issuer
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature
extendedKeyUsage = codeSigning
```

and finaly use following command to sign foo.exe:

```
openssl cms -sign -nosmimecap -signer signcert.pem -inkey signcert_pri.pem -binary -in foo.exe -outform der -out foo.cert.cms -certfile codeca.pem
```

cms will successfully generated! but with missing null after OID '2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1'!!

I can't understand where I missed.

---

I manged to fix issue by changing:
openssl cms
to
openssl smime

Answer (score 1):

Per https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4055#section-2.1, what OpenSSL has done is correct:

> There are two possible encodings for the AlgorithmIdentifier
> parameters field associated with these object identifiers. ...
> Because of this
> history some implementations encode parameters as a NULL element
> while others omit them entirely.  **The correct encoding is to omit the
> parameters field**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

If you're loading the CMS into another system that can't read it properly, that's a bug on the other system, because that portion goes on to say

> All implementations MUST accept both NULL and absent parameters as
> legal and equivalent encodings.